# Why is this axios get request not being entered from within this while loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web-scraping, cheerio

```
app.get('/api/fighter', (req,res) => {

let userAgent = "";
userAgent = randomUseragent.getRandom();
//set req headers to random user agent
req.headers['user-agent'] = userAgent;

    //for now i will hard code what the req query params would be
    let firstName = "jon"
    let lastName = "jones"
    //step 1 search for fighter to retreive fighter profile url
    let initalUrlToScrape = 'https://www.sherdog.com/stats/fightfinder?SearchTxt='+firstName+'+'+lastName+'&weight=&association=';
    //add more headers to the request
    request(initalUrlToScrape,{headers:{ 'User-Agent': req.headers['user-agent']}},(error, response, html) => {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            
            let fighterNameFound = $('html.light .new_table tr:nth-child(even):not(.table_head)');
            let fighterNameIndex = $('.new_table td a');
            let nameToCompare = firstName + ' ' + lastName;
            let fighterFound = false;
            let next=0;
            let page = 1;
            while (!fighterFound) {
                
                console.log(fighterNameIndex[next].children[0].data.toLowerCase());

                if(fighterNameIndex[next].children[0].data.toLowerCase() == nameToCompare.toLowerCase()){
                    fighterNameIndex = fighterNameIndex[next];
                    console.log(fighterNameIndex.attribs.href);
                    break;
                }else if(next==fighterNameFound.length-1){
                    next=0;                    
                   //axios request for next page. update the fighterNameIndex and fighterNameFound
                     axios({
                        url: 'https://www.sherdog.com/stats/fightfinder?association=&weightclass=&SearchTxt=jon+jones&page=2',
                      }).then(function (response) {
                        response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('ada_lovelace.jpg'))
                      })
                    .catch(error3 => {
                        console.log(error3);
                    });
                }else{
                    next++;
                }     
            }
            // for(let x = 0; x < fighterNameFound.length; x++){
            //     // console.log(fighterNameIndex.attribs.href);
            //     // fighterNameIndex = fighterNameIndex[x];
            //     // console.log(fighterNameIndex.attribs.href);
            //     console.log(fighterNameIndex[x].children[0].data.toLowerCase());
            //     //check if the fighter name found is the same as the one we are looking for
            //     if(fighterNameIndex[x].children[0].data.toLowerCase() == nameToCompare.toLowerCase()){
            //         fighterNameIndex = fighterNameIndex[x];
            //         console.log(fighterNameIndex.attribs.href);
            //         break;
            //     }else if(x==fighterNameFound.length-1){

            //     }                
            // }
            //  enhancedProfileUrlFoundOnPage = fighterNameIndex.attribs.href;

            //step 2 navigate to fighter profile url and scrape everything
            let profileUrlToScrape = 'https://www.sherdog.com'+enhancedProfileUrlFoundOnPage
             request(profileUrlToScrape, {headers:{ 'User-Agent': req.headers['user-agent']}},(error1, response1, html2) => {

                if (!error1 && response1.statusCode == 200) {
                    const $ = cheerio.load(html2);
                    
                    //find element
                    const fullName = $('.fighter-title h1 .fn');
                    const nickName = $('.fighter-title h1 .nickname, .fighter-title h1 .nickname_empty');
                    const birthCountry = $('.fighter-title .birthplace strong');
                    const fightingOutOf = $('span.locality');
                    const flag = $('.fighter-title .big_flag');
                    const wins = $('div.winloses.win span');
                    const losses = $('div.winloses.lose span');
                    const weightClass = $('body > div.wrapper > div.inner-wrapper > div.col-left > div > section:nth-child(3) > div > div.fighter-info > div.fighter-right > div.fighter-data > div.bio-holder > div > a');

                    
                    //scrape the data
                    const fullnameValue = $(fullName).text();
                    const nickNameValue = $(nickName).text();
                    const birthCountryValue = $(birthCountry).text();
                    const fightingOutOfValue = $(fightingOutOf).text();
                    const flagValue = $(flag).attr('src');
                    const winsValue = $(wins).text();
                    const lossesValue = $(losses).text();
                    const weightClassValue = $(weightClass).text();
                    
           

                  //push data found to global array
                  data.push({
                    name: fullnameValue,
                    nickname: nickNameValue,
                    country: birthCountryValue,
                    fightingOutOf: fightingOutOfValue,
                    flag: "https://www.sherdog.com"+flagValue,
                    wins: winsValue.replace("Wins",""),
                    losses: lossesValue.replace("Losses",""),
                    weightClass: weightClassValue

                  
                  })
                  res.send(data);
                }
                });
        }
        });   

});
```

I am creating a web scraping and i need this while loop present because i need to check each page until the fighter i want is found. In the while loop, as soon as the current array data element is finished i need to request the next page, but the request is skipped. Why is the axios request ignored?

Comment: axios is async but you're not awaiting anything. All synchronous code runs to completion before async is dealt with. That means all loops will end before the `then` runs.

Comment: @ggorlen but all the other requests are synchronous too?

Comment: No, all requests are async, either with promises or callbacks. If you have axios, you might as well use it throughout rather than `request`.